# jQuery Global Variable in Each Statement

Tags: javascript, jquery

So, I am trying to make it so I can create a variable globally throughout my whole document with jQuery, but inside of an .each() statement.

Where I put "var previous = item.channel.display_name" is the variable I am trying to create.

Code:

```
jQuery(function(){ 
var streams = null;
jQuery.getJSON("https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/search/streams?q=path%20of%20exile&callback=?", function (data) {
    streams =  data.streams;
    jQuery("#next").show();
    jQuery("#prev").show();
    jQuery("#next").click();
});

var globalCnt = 0;
jQuery("#next").click(function() {
    var localCnt = 0;
    var itemsToShow = 1;
         jQuery.each(streams, function (index, item) {
             localCnt++;
             if(localCnt > globalCnt && itemsToShow > 0) {
             jQuery("#content").empty();
             jQuery("#content").html('<object style="margin-left:0.5%;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '" bgcolor="#000000"><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true" /><param name="allowScriptAccess" value="always" /><param name="allowNetworking" value="all" /><param name="movie" value="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf" /><param name="flashvars" value="hostname=www.twitch.tv&channel=' + item.channel.display_name + '&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" /></object><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=' + item.channel.display_name +'&amp;popout_chat=true" height="378" width="350"></iframe>');
                 globalCnt++;
                 itemsToShow--;
                 var previous = item.channel.display_name;
             }
        });
    if(itemsToShow > 0)
        jQuery("#showBtn").hide();
});
jQuery("#prev").click(function() {
    var localCnt = 0;
    var itemsToShow = 1;
         jQuery.each(streams, function (index, item) {
             localCnt++;
             if(localCnt > globalCnt && itemsToShow > 0) {
             jQuery("#content").empty();
             document.write(previous);
             jQuery("#content").html('<object style="margin-left:0.5%;" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" height="378" width="620" id="live_embed_player_flash" data="http://www.twitch.tv/widgets/live_embed_player.swf?channel=' + previous + '&auto_play=false&start_volume=25" /></object><iframe frameborder="0" scrolling="no" id="chat_embed" src="http://twitch.tv/chat/embed?channel=' + previous +'&amp;popout_chat=true" height="378" width="350"></iframe>');
                 globalCnt++;
                 itemsToShow--;
             } 
        });
    if(itemsToShow > 0)
        jQuery("#showBtn").hide();
});
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing wrong with creating global variables, but you must be sure of some things if you want to do it properly.

- If possible add just one global variable and then wrap all your code on that variable. Not good idea to create many global variables.
- In your case, you should create something like: var myApp = myApp || {}
  That is: myApp is equal to myApp (if it already exists or myApp will be an empty object if myApp doesn´t exists previously.

Then, this line: 
var previous = item.channel.display_name;

will become: 
myApp.previous = item.channel.display_name.

Comment: Ohkk I understand now. But how would I structure this to actually work in my script? I know how to create the global variable now but how do I make it save the data under previous as the previous data before you click next and then if you click previous it will load that previous data. Do you understand what I mean or should I try to word it differently?

Comment: Yes, I understand. The thing is that if you iterate over and over again your script will always store the latest value in your next and previous values.

If I were you I would try to build an array like this.

    var myStreams = []  //Declare the array we´re going to use.
   
    //your each iteration
    myMap[n] = yourStream.

When the loop is complete, you´ll have your streams kind of mapped in an array, so if you get the index of your stream, you can bring the next video and previos, by substracting or adding 1 to your index. Just an idea...

Comment: I've never used "maps" or however you call them before. I guess you could say I'm not very advanced with jQuery or very good for that matter. I'm still learning, do you think it would be possible for you to send me a jsFiddle of an example of this map function. Although don't do it with my code because than I would just be copying and pasting, I wouldn't learn much.

Comment: Don´t worry let me think and build a jsfiddle.

Comment: Still there? @Guillermo

Comment: I'm here, I've coded a pretty basic example, it's kind of videoplayer, it´s just a proof of concept. If you press play, the first "video" (a string) will be showed in the "screen", if you press next, nothing will happen visually, but the index of the play button will be changed to play the next video, and so on. For example you can add more features to next, when pressing button, you can bring the next video poster or something like that. Previous button doesn´t work. It´s just for the sake of showing you the concept.

Code should be refactored, but there you have. Tell me if you get the idea.

Comment: Remember, press play. Then next, then play. You´ll see how it works.

Comment: I'm sorry if I seem noobish, I looked at the code, but I am still a bit confused on how this would work. Can you test it in jsfiddle.net with my code and just tell me the steps or send me the code with comments possibly? I am getting more and more confused D:

Comment: Any luck with the jsfiddle? :)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not condoning global variables, but if you want to create one inside of another scope, you'd add it to the `window` object:

```
window.globalVal = "foo";
```

`window` is a property on the global object that points to itself.  Adding properties to it is tantamount to creating a global variable.

So for your case, you can do

```
window.previous = item.channel.display_name;
```

and then access previous from anywhere—assuming it's not shadowed, of course.  On that last note, I'd be remiss if I didn't mention that global variables are generally a bad idea.  Use them with extreme caution.

Comment: This worked! Thanks man! Although the functionality of my script doesn't work, as you can tell by this script I want the previous button to bring you to the previous object and the next to bring you to the next object. Check it out live here -> http://codeeplus.net/new.php and tell me if you see the error

Comment: @user3023566 - awesome.  If one of these answers answered your question, be sure to accept it (I'd recommend Guillermo's answer - it's much better than mine)